# Possible DDOS, where to find? what logs?

Tags: apache, logging

Some months ago the server was under a DDOS attack. (my sys admin found out)
At this moment the sys admin is not available, and the server went down several times.

How can i find out if I am under attack? What log files?

SSH, APACHE were not available, but i could ping the server. Then I reset the server, and everything functions again. I think they do a short attack and then the server crashes.
From what I know from the last attackers, they are just some idiots, no real 'hackers'.

What I found in the syslog, the last log before server went down:
WEBSERVERUSER - MAIL (mailed 260 bytes of output but got status 0x0001 )

What logs to check more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What logs to check depends on what **OS**, what **version**, what server software is installed and **how it's configured**.

Basically apache web server (most used) has access logs here:

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
```

and error logs here:

```
/var/log/httpd/error_log
```

SSH by default on RHEL logs to

```
/var/log/secure
```

or to syslog

```
/var/log/messages
```

I used denyhost tool to detect & prevent brute force attacks on SSHD.

There are lots of analyzers available, just google for IDS, but I can not recommend you specific until you give us more details mentioned above.